# What to do If your pedal are squeaking and are not straight?

Tags: frames, pedals

I have a dtb and the pedals aren't straight they are kind of bent It seems that something is broken in the place where they are join.

**update**: It's moving sideways and the outer bolt are quite slanty You know not tightened properly And when I shake it It feels something is broken inside

Comment: Sounds like your bottom bracket is wobbly.  If you push a pedal sideways, does the one on the other side move too?   If yes, your bottom bracket needs tweaking, or rebuilding, or replacing with a new cartridge.

Comment: The most common problem (and unfortunately not a cheap one to fix) is that the crank arms (on a 3-piece crank) have become loose where they join to the axle.  If this is the case then you can TRY tightening the bolts that hold the crank arms in place, but usually by the time you notice this situation the arms (and possibly the crank) have been damaged beyond repair and need replacing.  Grab hold of a pedal and shake it and see where it's loose.

Answer (score 1):

A 3-piece crank:

[image]

A 1-piece crank:

[image]

Which do you have??